# Streaming data from Cosmos DB using Apache Spark 3

Tags: apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, azure-databricks

Streaming from CosmosDB using Spark 2 connector can be achieved using Changefeed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/spark-connector#streaming-reads-from-cosmos-db

How do we do the same in Spark 3? I am using Cosmos DB Apache Spark 3 OLTP Connector for SQL API (beta).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-sql-api-spark#query-cosmos-db

Answer (score 0):

Right now there is no released version of CosmosDB connector that supports Spark 3.  But you can compile connector yourself from the [3.0 branch](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark/compare/3.0) - it works for me, including the changefeed

Update based on the comment: beta versions are available: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-java-spark-v3

Comment: Do you mean to say, I need to compile and use the jar generated from the pointed branch? Will try it out. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: More details, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-java-spark-v3

Comment: It’s really strange that they don’t have any mention in repository itself :-( thank you Mark - it would be better if you submit this as answer

Comment: Thank you, Mark and Alex. 

As I have mentioned in my question, I used the beta version library only. Still, I could see there are changes in the Query (Read and Write) format. It would be a great help if you could point the way Streaming is to be done with the Spark3 connector. I have attached the doc to streaming using Spark2 with Cosmos Changefeed in the question.